# how to change color of a button when checkbox is selected in java?

Tags: java

i don't know how to link the check boxes and button together to change the colour of button.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import javax.swing.*;
import com.sun.glass.events.MouseEvent;

public class Simple extends Applet 
{  
    Button b;
    public void init()
{
    b=new Button("Here"); b.setBackground(Color.white);
    add(b);
    b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
    {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me)
        {
            b.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me)
        {
            b.setBackground(Color.white);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

this is the example i tried but this also didn't work for me.

Comment: There is no checkbox in your example. Also, you shouldn't use AWT. You should even less use applets, which are officially abandoned.

Comment: @JBNizet then what should i use ?

Comment: JavaFX, or Swing at least. And make a real application, not an applet.

Comment: _"make a real application, not an applet."_ —or— if you are making something to run on the web, learn HTML5, CSS3, Javascript, and the DOM. jQuery and other javascript enhancements are also useful. You _can_ still use Java on _the **server**_.

Answer (score 0):

You have to repaint the container, not the object.

```
b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
    {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me)
        {
            b.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            this.repaint();
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me)
        {
            b.setBackground(Color.white);
            this.repaint();
        }
    });
```